# Upload a git repository on google drive

Tags: git, cmake

Hello I have git repos containing compiled languages (C++, python, and few others), somewhere where I can't plug a flash usb, so I tried to upload these on google drive and download these somewhere else. I did it mainly for the src folders, not devel build and include folders if I remember well.

You may say it's dumb, and I should simply clone the repos on the other machine, but some are not hosted on github, or some are private and were provided in the machine1 but I'm not allowed to have access to these on github. Still, I have to transfer these on a machine2 for hardware reasons and can't wait for                                                                                                                                                                                                      admins in holidays.

So I got issues recompiling everything, and so is it possible to upload the whole packages to google drive, with google drive not forgetting any hidden or exotic file ? Such as those generated by the build ?

Comment: It is not clear which files you want to upload to the google drive. If by "Such as those generated by the build?" you mean files generated by CMake, then take into account, that these files cannot be used anywhere except the machine they are created on.

Comment: Any reason you can't upload it all as a tar ball?